# Mapstruct map nested attribute to target v1.3.1.Final

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I'd like to know if it is possible to write a straightforward mapping for this example using Mapstruct 1.3.1.Final (I cannot upgrade for project related reasons):

```
List<A> mapBToList(B b);
```

with `B` being:

```
public class B {
    private List<C> c;
}
```

`A` and `C` have the same attributes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about straightforward, but something like this would definitely work:

```
List<A> mapCListToAList(List<C> c);

default List<A> mapBToList(B b){
    return mapCListToAList(b.getC();
}
```

Comment: yeah, I already know this solution, I was just wondering about a more immediate one, without having to create intermediate methods

Comment: This is the only way to do this currently